# Not able to run java code in the background using sh file

Tags: java, shell, jar, nohup, dev-null

My SH file:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

DIR="$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")/"

cd "$DIR"

javac -cp "streamer-client-java.jar:kafka-clients-3.4.0.jar:lz4-java-1.8.0.jar:slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar:snappy-java-1.1.10.0.jar:." EnduserCredentialExample.java

java -cp "streamer-client-java.jar:kafka-clients-3.4.0.jar:lz4-java-1.8.0.jar:slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar:snappy-java-1.1.10.0.jar:." EnduserCredentialExample.java

echo "JAVA_KAFKA script running now"
```

The above code is my SH script, and I'm not able to run it in the background.

We tried it using the following command:

```bash
nohup java -cp "streamer-client-java.jar:kafka-clients-3.4.0.jar:lz4-java-1.8.0.jar:slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar:snappy-java-1.1.10.0.jar:." EnduserCredentialExample.java > output.log 2> error.log &

java -cp "streamer-client-java.jar:kafka-clients-3.4.0.jar:lz4-java-1.8.0.jar:slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar:snappy-java-1.1.10.0.jar:." EnduserCredentialExample.java > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

If I run this command, it triggers the script, and the script starts running, but after 5 seconds, the script stops running.

```
java -cp "streamer-client-java.jar:kafka-clients-3.4.0.jar:lz4-java-1.8.0.jar:slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar:snappy-java-1.1.10.0.jar:." EnduserCredentialExample.java
```

If I run this command without `nohup` and
`/dev/null 2>&1 &` manually in the terminal, and it's working fine. How can I run this in the background?

Comment: What's in the output files with `java -cp jar_file1.jar:jar_file2.jar MyJavaCode >output.log 2> error.log`? i.e. don't worry about backgrounding it until, **a.** the basic command is correct and **b.** you have proved it will run correctly in the foreground. And *cd ${DIR}* would be better as `cd "$DIR"`

Comment: You can use 'tmux' to run in the background.

Comment: To install it in Linux:
  `sudo apt-get install tmux`

Comment: @user16320675 If I run like java ... MyjavaClass, I recceived following error 
Error: could not find or load main class MyjavaClass
caused by: java.langNoClassDefFoundError: path/to/JavaClass (wrong name: MyjavaClass)

Comment: @g00se I had my intended output lines in my output.log file, and I saw no errors.

Comment: @user16320675, please accept my apologies. MyJavaCode is the name. I tried the command "java -cp path/to/jar1.jar:path/to/jar2.jar MyJavaCode" and received the following errors: 
"Could not find or load main class MyJavaCode. 
Caused by: java.langNoClassDefFoundError: path/to/JavaClass (wrong name: MyJavaCode)".
MyJavaCode.class can be found in my directory.

Comment: Then there's no reason you can't background it. Prefer `tmux` over `nohup` or better still, if it's a service then use a service wrapper

Comment: @user16320675 Now I have changed eeerything to jar. 
When I use the command '''java -jar Myjar.jar''', the code runs well. However, when I try to run it in the background using the command '''nohup java -jar Mylar.jar &''', it fails.